# How to adjust canvas images relative to viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I am trying to make canvas layer image responsive to canvas background image, both are showing there good responsive behavior , but my problem is that I want to fix the layer image in the center of the screen whether what size of screen. Currently on re-sizing my layer image start to change its position that is undesirable. I want to fix layer image right in the center of screen

here is my html code

```
<body id="body">

    <canvas id="myCanvas" style="position:relative;"></canvas>


    <img src="background.jpg" id="background" />
    <img src="s01.jpg" id="layer" />
```

here is my css

```
#layer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    margin-left: -160px;
}

img{
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        max-width:100%;
        max-height:100%;
    }

body {
        /*background: #E9E9E9;*/
        color: #333;
        font: 1em/1.3em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 0 1px 0;
        text-align: center;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    html, body {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
    }
```

and here is my js

```
(function() {
    var

        htmlCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
        context = htmlCanvas.getContext('2d');

    var background = document.getElementById('background');
    context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    initialize();

    function initialize() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
        resizeCanvas();
    }

    function redraw() {
        context.strokeStyle = 'transparent';
        context.lineWidth = '5';
        context.strokeRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        var background = document.getElementById('background');
        context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        };
        imageObj.src = 'background.jpg';

    }
    function resizeCanvas() {
        htmlCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        htmlCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        redraw();
    }
})();
```

I am stuck here for last 3 days, still unable to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any problem in your script. It's well written. But you just need to apply this css rule to center the layer in the viewport:

```
#layer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0qurqh1m/)

Comment: Yeah, Its pretty helpful but now the problem is the width of layer image, can you tell how to fix it auto with the screen

Comment: define the max-width in percentage.